# Why compare index to -1?

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, while-loop

In the following code they check that the index is not equal to -1 and equal to -1.  Why are they checking that?  What dose the -1 signify?

```
import java.util.*;


class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = s.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            String str = s.next();

            int index = 0;
            int index1=0 , index2=0, count1=0, count2=0;

            while(index != -1)
            {
                index1 = str.indexOf("SUVOJIT");
                index2 = str.indexOf("SUVO");

                if(index1==index2)
                {
                    if(index1==-1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    count1++;
                    str = str.substring(index1 + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    count2++;
                    str = str.substring(index2 + 1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("SUVO = "+count2+", SUVOJIT = "+count1);             
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: try reading docs of `indexOf`

Comment: The code seems buggy: `index` is never updated in the loop. It think they rather want `while (index2 != -1)`.

Comment: @PavneetSingh thank you sir..!

Answer (score 2):

It is very simply:

-1 is the value that [String.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) returns when there is no index in that string that carries the corresponding char/character sequence.

Quoting javadoc:

*Returns:*
*the index of the first occurrence of the specified substring, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.*

So, the *real* answer here is: start by reading the existing, available documentation for the library methods that are used in your code!

And, as the comments point out: that code is buggy in the first place; as the loop control variable (index) is initialized to 0; and never changed afterwards; leading to an infinite loop.